# Angular material active tab label color changes when clicking away

Tags: tabs, angular-material

I overrode the mat-tab-label-active to change the color of the active tab to a custom color (yellow) but when I click anywhere in the page the color changes and becomes dirty like there is another layer of faded color on top of it ([see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4YJX.png)) . How do I keep the color of the active tab just like when it's clicked all the time/until changing tab ?

my code :

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
  background-color: #FCE500;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The opacity and background color is changed dynamically based on focus. You need to control that. Something like

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active:not(.mat-tab-disabled),
::ng-deep.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active.cdk-keyboard-focused:not(.mat-tab-disabled) {
  background-color: #FCE500;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I don't recommend changing the opacity because if you make it always '1' it looks like the tab has focus when it does not - you can't tell the difference - not a good user experience.

Comment: Thank you. The opacity part was the missing part in mine.

Comment: Thank you. The opacity part was the missing part in mine.

Comment: reading that `::ng-deep` will be deprecated instead we need to use `viewEncapsulation.None` in the component properties where we define the styleUrls and templateUrls  such as written here in the docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Answer (score 1):

It has already been answered, but I encountered the same problem but fixed it with another solution since the other answers didn't really fit with my preferences. This is what I did:

(Here's a working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-focussed)

I declared my tabs for the navigation. And declared a SelectionModel.

```
  public tabs = [
    {value: 'Stepper', link: './stepper'},
    {value: 'Quotations', link: './quotations'},
    {value: 'Designs', link: './designs'},
    {value: 'Elements', link: './elements'},
    ];
  private selection = new SelectionModel();
```

In my HTML it looks like this:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar class="tabs-group">
  <a *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="select(tab)" mat-tab-link [routerLink]="tab.link" 
     class="header-btn" [ngClass]="{focus: isSelected(tab)}">
    <a>{{tab.value}}</a>
  </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet class="router-outlet-small"></router-outlet>
```

I got two methods which will do the selection. I also want to select the first tab as default. The select() method will select the tab, the isSelected() method will take care of the CSS within the [ngClass] statement in the tab HTML.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.selection.select(this.tabs[0]); // Will select the first tab.
  }

  select(tab) {
    if (!this.selection.isSelected(tab)) {
      this.selection.clear(); // Only one tab can be selected in this way
      this.selection.select(tab);
    }
  }

  isSelected(tab): boolean {
    return this.selection.isSelected(tab);
  }
```

The isSelected() method will return true/false which will trigger the styling class to header-btn.focus which is shown below in my css.

```
.header-btn {
 // My css
}

.header-btn.focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is kind of annoying with the faded color (maybe depending on the color combination used on the page).

I had the tab definition as:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and the following css rule helped set the opacity to 1

```
.mat-ripple.mat-tab-label.mat-focus-indicator.mat-tab-label.ng-star-inserted {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I had the ripple effect enabled, if you have it disabled, maybe the mat-ripple selector might have to be removed from the rule.